# How to correctly use short Swift closures in calls to ObjC classes

Tags: swift, closures, nsindexset

I want to use short form of closure `{$0 > 1}` in calls to `NSIndexSet` class:

```
let indexSet: NSIndexSet = getSomeIndexSet()
let filteredIndexSet = indexSet.indexesPassingTest(){$0 > 1}
```

but it gives me

> Cannot invoke 'indexesPassingTest' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'

but this works: `indexSet.indexesPassingTest(){(i,s) in i > 1}` though type names are still not there.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says what you are doing wrong. The argument passed to block are not two different argument rather a single argument which is tuple. So, you will have to access each element in from the tuple.

Based on the comment by Martin R, it seems like closure must match the 2 arguments. So, one can use $0, or $1 or if only one is used then $0 becomes tuple.

```
let filteredIndexSet = indexSet.indexesPassingTest { $0.0 > 20 }
```

The **$0.0** means the first item in the tuple which is index.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Never would thought of this! And what's the difference from Array.reduce combine closure?

Comment: You can *either* use `$0` **and** `$1` (in which case `$0` is the index and `$1` is the boolean pointer) *or* just `$0` (which is then a tuple consisting of index and pointer). Compare https://devforums.apple.com/message/1117149#1117149. The "problem" is that you cannot "omit" unused shorthand arguments.

Comment: @AlexeyMartemyanov: There is no difference.

Comment: @MartinR, Is this a reasonable way how arguments should work inside closure. This seems to be some kind of bug to me.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne: I don't know if it is a bug or intended, that's why I posted in the Developer Forum.